# React как отправить api запрос

Tags: api, react-native

Помогите пожалуйста как в реакте отправить апи запрос на сайт, допустим есть сайт
[http://api.host.ru/name/name2/push?token=тут](http://api.host.ru/name/name2/push?token=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82) данные&time=2022-04-21 22:00:00&id=тут данные&platform_id=1196532&firstname=Вася
При попытки отправить этот запрос через fetch пишет 400 ошибку, хотя при переходе по ссылки запрос работает